# Python member function returns non-const reference to internal - need pythonian fix

Tags: python, reference, return

I have made a small Encryptor class, that takes a word (a `string`) as input, and returns a `list` of `string`s. The encryption is slow, so I cache the result, in case I want to encrypt the same word again. (In the code below actual encryption has been replaced with some dummy code)
The following code does not work, because `encrypt` returns a non-const reference to an internal.
What would be a nice pythonian way to solve this?
I need to be able to use it with both `=` and `+=` as shown.

```
class Encryptor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def encrypt(self, word):
        if word in self.cache:
            return self.cache[word]
        encrypted = list("<" + word + ">")
        self.cache[word] = encrypted
        return encrypted


encryptor = Encryptor()

encrypted_text = encryptor.encrypt("this")
encrypted_text += encryptor.encrypt("is")
encrypted_text += encryptor.encrypt("good")
encrypted_text += encryptor.encrypt("this")
encrypted_text += encryptor.encrypt("is")
encrypted_text += encryptor.encrypt("not")

print("".join(encrypted_text))
```

Expected output:

```
<this><is><good><this><is><not>
```

Actual output:

```
<this><is><good><this><is><good><is><not>
```

Comment: Make a tuple instead of list, where you do encrypted = tuple("<" + word + ">")

Comment: To elaborate on @user1767754 and @jotasi - since you are using `+=` on a `list`, and lists are mutable, you're changing that `list`. The very same `list` object is stored at `encryptor.cache["this"]`, and thus that changes as well. Either return a copy or use `tuple`s.

Comment: Why are you even using intermediate lists? Just use `str`. Or keep a list accumulator external to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "**memoization**". In a pythonic way this is solved via Decorator's. You can basically define a Decorator that looks up an item in the dictionary and returns it and if there is nothing, it generates new data.

Here is an example for your case: (Btw I wouldn't use lists for your Problem but strings or other hashable types)

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.memo = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.memo:
        self.memo[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memo[args]


@Memoize
def encrypt(word):
    return tuple("<" + word + ">")

encrypted_text = encrypt("1")
encrypted_text += encrypt("2")
encrypted_text += encrypt("3")
encrypted_text += encrypt("1")

print("".join(encrypted_text))
```

More Info: 
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

Answer (score 0):

`list.__iadd__(other)` is implemented as :

```
self.extend(other)
return self
```

so by calling `+=` on the list returned you do mutate the cached value.

The solution is plain simple: dont store a list, store a string and make it a list (if you really need a list) just before returning...

```
def encrypt(self, word):
    if word not in self.cache:        
        self.cache[word] = "<" + word + ">"
    return list(self.cache[word])
```

or better let the client take responsibility of making this a list (or whatever):

```
def encrypt(self, word):
    if word not in self.cache:        
        self.cache[word] = "<" + word + ">"
    return self.cache[word]
```

and then

```
encryptor = Encryptor()

encrypted_text = list(encryptor.encrypt("this"))
encrypted_text += list(encryptor.encrypt("is"))
encrypted_text += list(encryptor.encrypt("good"))
```

etc